# How can I send a statement to be used as a command within code?

Tags: javascript

What I've been trying to do is to pass a statement like `oninput` or `onmouseover` and then use them as actual statements in a method.

```js
function Controller() {
  this.listen = function(elem, func, statement) {
    elem.statement = function() {//and then use it here
      func(elem);
    };
    return true;
  };
}

var age = document.getElementById('age');
var controller = new Controller();

controller.listen(age, callMe, oninput);//set the statement here

function callMe(elem) {
  console.log('hey');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="number" id="age" />
</body>

</html>
```

**Is there a way to do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `oninput` as a string (`"oninput"`) and then use square brackets to access the property of `elem`:

```
function Controller() {
  this.listen = function(elem, func, statement) {
    elem[statement] = function() {//and then use it here
      func(elem);
    };
    return true;
  };
}

var age = document.getElementById('age');
var controller = new Controller();

controller.listen(age, callMe, "oninput");//set the statement here

function callMe(elem) {
  console.log('hey');
}
```

However, I recommend you using `element.addEventListener()` instead of `.onevent`, see [addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35093997/3853934).